# how to get GridView item position x,y correctly

Tags: android, gridview, position

i want to set position of dialog at the same position where it is clicked..like this

[image]

but i am getting this

[image]

here is my code to position dialog..

```
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {
        float positionX = v.getX();
        float positionY = v.getY();

        LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout) gvGrid.getFocusedChild();

        dialog = new Dialog(CW_Emergency.this);
        dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.view_pager_layout);
        dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(android.graphics.Color.TRANSPARENT));

        //position of popup
        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes();
        params.x = (int) positionX;
        params.y = (int) positionY;

        ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(container, CW_Emergency.this);
        viewPager = (ViewPager) dialog.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);

        dialog.show();



    }
```

kindly tell me how to position it correctly for all screen sizes

Comment: have you tried without set position of dialog box ?

Comment: yeah.. its appearing in center of screen

Answer (score 0):

You can use PopupWindow.

```
 mPopupWindow = new PopupWindow(
                    customView,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            );
```

and show it

```
mPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(ItemInGridView, 0, -1 * ItemInGridView.getHeight(), Gravity.LEFT);
```

Answer (score 0):

According to me To Display Dialog at correct position **PopupMenu** would be more convenient and simple. To implement PopupMenu ...

1. First you have to create menu resource file inside menu resource folder

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
   <item android:id="@+id/menu_option1"
     android:title="Option 1"
     />
   <item android:id="@+id/menu_option2"
     android:title="Option 2"
     />
   </menu>
   ```
2. Implement the following code inside your **onItemClick()** method

   ```
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View v, int position, long id) {

   PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(this, v);
   // Inflate the menu from xml
   popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.popup_menu, popup.getMenu());
   // Setup menu item selection
   popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
       public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
           switch (item.getItemId()) {
           case R.id.menu_option1:
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Option 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               return true;
           case R.id.menu_option2:
               Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Option 2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               return true;
           default:
               return false;
           }
       }
   });
   // Show the menu
   popup.show();

    }
   ```

The PopupMenu will be shown exactly near the view on which you will click.